# Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am working on maintenance project which is migrated from Rails 3.2.13 to Rails 4.2.
Here there is a scenario where when I upload a photo / indicator, it will be stored in AWS.
But, when I submit the data, I am facing the below error:

> New RightAws::S3Interface using shared connections mode Opening new
>   HTTPS connection to nudge.development.s3.amazonaws.com:443 Opening new
>   HTTPS connection to s3.amazonaws.com:443 Completed 500 Internal Server
>   Error in 3816ms (ActiveRecord: 14.4ms)
>   ** [Airbrake] Notice was not sent due to configuration:            Environment Monitored? false            API key set? true
>
> Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /home/myproject/public/photo_screenshots/128.png:
>   lib/screenshot.rb:43:in `upload'   lib/screenshot.rb:8:in`initialize'
>   app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:221:in `send_report_email'
>
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in`
>   send_action'
>   .....................................................................................
>   .....................................................................................

This is my code:

lib/screenshot.rb:

```
class Screenshot
  attr_reader :user_id, :report_id, :type

  def initialize(user_id, report_id, type)
      @user_id, @report_id, @type = user_id, report_id, type
      capture
      resize(500, 686) if @type == 'report_screenshots'
      upload    # this is line no 8 which is showing error
      delete_local_copy
  end


  def upload
    file_name = Rails.root.join("public/#{@type}/#{@report_id}.png")
    s3config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 's3.yml'))[Rails.env]
    s3 = RightAws::S3.new(s3config["access_key_id"], s3config["secret_access_key"])
    @type == 'report_screenshots' ? s3.bucket("nudge.#{Rails.env}", true).put("#{@type}/#{@report_id}.png", File.open(file_name), {}, 'public-read', { 'content-type' => 'image/png' }) : s3.bucket("nudge.#{Rails.env}", true).put("indicator_screenshots/#{@report_id}.png", File.open(file_name), {}, 'public-read', { 'content-type' => 'image/png' }) # this is line no 43 which is showing error
    report = Report.find(@report_id)
    @type == 'report_screenshots' ? report.update_attribute(:report_screenshot_at, Time.now) : report.update_attribute(:indicator_screenshot_at, Time.now)
  end

  ..................................................

end
```

reports_controller:

```
def send_report_email
   if @report.photos.empty?
      Rails.env.development? ? Screenshot.new(@user.id, @report.id, Rails.application.config.custom.indicator_screenshots) :             Screenshot.delay.new(@user.id, @report.id, Rails.application.config.custom.indicator_screenshot_bucket)
    else
      Rails.env.development? ? Screenshot.new(@user.id, @report.id, "photo_screenshots") : Screenshot.delay.new(@user.id, @report.id, "photo_screenshots")
    end
end
```

Please help.

Comment: Does the file it mentions exist? If not what is supposed to be creating it?

Comment: If I comment the 43rd line in upload method  before the s3.bucket as  `@type == 'report_screenshots' #? s3.bucket("nudge.#{Rails.env}", true).put("#{@type}/#{@report_id}.png", File.open(file_name), {}, 'public-read', { 'content-type' => 'image/png' }) : s3.bucket("nudge.#{Rails.env}", true).put("indicator_screenshots/#{@report_id}.png", File.open(file_name), {}, 'public-read', { 'content-type' => 'image/png' })`, it is working fine. The problem mostly lies in this line. There might be syntax / declaration problem I think.